# Call a VBA sub using a string value

Tags: vba, excel

This is my test code

```
Sub dotask()

    Dim qusub As String
    qusub = Worksheets("Task List").Range("C2").Value

    MsgBox qusub
    Application.Run qusub

End Sub

Sub msg1()

    MsgBox "sub msg1"

End Sub

Sub msg2()

    MsgBox "sub msg2"

End Sub

Sub msg3()

    MsgBox "sub msg3"

End Sub

Sub msg4()

    MsgBox "sub msg4"

End Sub
```

All of this is contained in a single standard module. I've read [Trying to call a Sub with a String - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969796/trying-to-call-a-sub-with-a-string-vba) and wrote my code according to what I found there (i.e. using Application.Run). Cell C2 of Task List worksheet contains "msg3" at the moment. When I execute sub "dotask" I first get a message box saying "msg3" as I want but then I get the following error message:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Cannot run the macro 'msg3'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

I'm working on Excel 2010 and the file is `.xlsm` - what should I do to get my code to execute as I want it?

Comment: Hmm, is this code contained in a module?

Comment: Yes, all of this is contained in a single module and it is the only module in this file

Comment: See this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845944/dynamic-function-calls-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just ran it over here. msg1 seems to be a reserved word... change it to something else and it works fine =)

Comment: `Application.Run "Module1.msg1"` worked too.  Weirdly, I can't even run the msg1 macro from the Macros dialog

Answer (score 1):

Using GetRef, you give the reference to the sub.
See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741292/vbscript-getref-with-parameter?s=51%7C5.0118) for example

EDIT: following the suggestions in the comments, here part of the solution to this question.

```
sub one(para)
  WScript.Echo para & " from one"
end sub

sub two(para)
  WScript.Echo para & " from two"
end sub

sub main(subname, para)
  Dim f : Set f = GetRef(subname)
  f para
end sub

main "one", "test" '=>test from one
```

Comment: This popped up in the Low Quality Post queue. I'm hitting skip, but I think this could use a teeny bit more explanation. :)